# SQL Server driver Python doesn't run properly on server

Tags: python, sql-server, server, driver

My connection

```
drivers = [item for item in pyodbc.drivers()]
driver = drivers[-1]
server1 = r'value'
database = 'value'
uid = 'user'
pwd = 'password'
con_string = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server1};DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PWD={pwd}'
conn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

I have a problem

> sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/rvf5)

This error did not happen when I ran on my laptop. It only occurs on the server.

Could you please tell me how I can solve it?

Comment: If you print the value of `driver` on the server what does it output? Is it the same driver that's used on your laptop?

Comment: Yes. It is SQL driver 17